# NameError: uninitialized constant Crawler::ScraperService on rails c

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to run a class on rails c for debug in a Rails project - duh - but I keep getting name error messages:

```
#app/services/scraper_service.rb

module Crawler
  class ScraperService
    URL_HOST = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/'
    
    def initialize(tag)
      @tag = tag
    end

    def self.get_url
      agent = Mechanize.new
      binding.pry
      page = agent.get(URL_HOST)
    end     
  end
end
```

When I try to instance the class on rails c, I get this:

```
> Crawler::ScraperService.new('love').get_url
NameError: uninitialized constant Crawler::ScraperService
from (pry):5:in `<main>'
```

Or without the initialize method (of course, in this case it's out of the code):

```
> Crawler::ScraperService.get_url
NameError: uninitialized constant Crawler::ScraperService
from (pry):7:in `<main>'
```

I know it's a little thing, but I'm trying to understand this.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, yes. Better never forget the "::" before this kind of call.

Right way:

`::Crawler::ScraperService.get_url` with the two :: before all the classes.